# C# create Pivot Charts OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, closedxml

Good morning,

I am creating a pivot table with closedxml, so far so good everything is working fine, does anyone knows how to create a chart associated with the pivot table (pivot chart) using ClosedXML or OpenXML.
Is it even possible or only normal charts?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no charting support in ClosedXML.

Comment: and in OpenXML?

Comment: It should be possible in OpenXML, but I don't know how.